# Matching windows system colors: light on dark

Tags: windows, systemcolors

I'm trying to make my app a good Windows citizen, so I use matching system colors (see ["When selecting system colors, match but don't mix"](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/12/6648399.aspx)) as much as possible. However, sometimes light text on a dark background (something like COLOR_APPWORKSPACE/clAppWorkSpace) seems most appropriate, but the system doesn't provide this. Do you have any recommendations regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could swap two colors. For example, if you can read InfoText colored text on a InfoBackground colored background, you should be able to read InfoBackground colored text on an Info colored background (or apply the concept to Window and WindowText).

Readability might suffer slightly.

Edit:

Sometimes it is okay to use your own colors, as long as they aren't mixed in with system colors (i.e. don't draw your color text on a system color background). If your own color scheme seems appropriate, then use it. Besides, Windows doesn't have a configurable color for every single need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried all the reversed combinations, but unfortunately they are either too colorful (title bar, highlight) or light on black which is *too* dark for my taste. :-)

Comment: Sometimes it is okay to use your own colors, as long as they aren't mixed in with system colors (i.e. don't draw your color text on a system color background). If your own color scheme seems appropriate, then use it. Besides, Windows doesn't have a configurable color for every single need.

Comment: I'd like to make this comment my accepted answer. Instead, I'll accept its "parent answer", even if that is *not* the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now: I set the background color to COLOR_APPWORKSPACE/clAppWorkSpace because I assume it has the "dark background" semantic I want. To get a contrasting text color I just get the [HLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) representation of the same color and increase its lightness factor.

Comment: Bad assumption. All the colors are configurable by the user, and someday you'll run into someone who has configured a light workspace.