# Matching background color for COLOR_GRAYTEXT

Tags: windows, systemcolors

(Related question to ["Matching windows system colors: light on dark"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559417/matching-windows-system-colors-light-on-dark).)

There doesn't seem to be an "official" background color for COLOR_GRAYTEXT. This looks strange to me. Do you know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming grayed out things can somehow be enabled, one would guess that both COLOR_3DFACE and the (tabbed) dialog texture will look ok